# Fixing a messed up rebase merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-reflog

I remember doing something like committing my changes(on my feature branch) and merging with a remote branch (not master). Then in order to make sure my commit came on top of the merge commit I rebased the last two commits and changed the order. I pushed these changes and others committed on top of this as well.

Now, what happened is that a few of the merge commits were picked with a different commit ID and now when I create a pull request it shows up as mine. I can understand this is because the same changes are in my branch from a different Commit ID so it shows up as someone else authored and I committed but the changes don't show up in the files tab since the changes are already there.

This is my reflog

```sh
HEAD@{12}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/my_branch_name

NEW COMMIT ID HEAD@{14}: rebase -i (pick): Messed up merge commit

NEW COMMIT ID HEAD@{15}: rebase -i (pick): Messed up merge commit

NEW COMMIT ID HEAD@{16}: rebase -i (pick): Messed up merge commit

NEW COMMIT ID HEAD@{17}: rebase -i (pick): Messed up merge commit
```

*And a few commits were added but others and me after this and this branch are used by a couple of other people. I am not sure how to fix this*.

One idea I can think of is to revert all these commits but that will create another 4 more commits.

Is there any way I can deal with this?

Comment: When you rebase a branch over a series of commits which contain one or more merge commits, you generally will have to redo the merges as you go along the rebase.  Most of the time, rebasing over merge commits is not what you want to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is undo what you've done so you can do it right.  You didn't mention what branch you're working with, so I'll assume it's `master`.

1. Look at your `reflog` and find the commit right before you started messing things up.
2. Make a note of the hash of that commit.
3. Do:

`git fetch origin master`

`git checkout -f master origin/master`

To save the "messed up" master branch under a new branch name, do:

`git branch messed-up-master`

`git push -u origin messed-up-master`

Now that it's saved, continue fixing as follows:

`git reset --hard HASH`

where HASH is the hash that you saved from the `reflog`.

`git push -f`

Now you're back where you were before the messup.  Then work on figuring out the right way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question. But after reset hard to before messed up changes and pushing them forcefully the commits others made after the messed up rebase will be lost, isn't it? so probably have to cherry-pic those?

Comment: Are those other commits on another branch?  If so, you can cherry-pick them from there.  If not, you can save them by creating a new branch.  I'll add those commands.